# Expresso Store not sending billing details to PayPal Express

Tags: expresso-store, paypal, paypal-express-checkout

I am using Expresso Store with PayPal Express checkout. When the user goes through the Store checkout they enter their billing details and once they are taken to the PayPal guest checkout the billing detail fields are blank apart from (first) name, telephone and email.  So the user has to enter their address details again.

Is there a way to get these fields automatically populated?

I've also noticed it's possible to enter billing details in PayPal that are different from those entered in Store, and the order in store shows the Store entered details rather than the PayPal details. (not sure if this is an issue or not).

I'm currently doing this on a MAMP install so i don't know if that is an issue, but it seems strange that email, name and phone are being passed through ok.

using store 1.6.1 and EE 2.4.0, with no easy way to upgrade.

Another question, I thought Paypal express had a mode where you would enter your card, shipping and billing details on the PayPal site and not on your site's checkout.  Does Store support that, I can't seem to find any information on how to set that up.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're using the correct Store tags when collecting the [Billing details](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#billing_details) on your site? You need to be using:

```
{field:billing_name}
{field:billing_address1}
{field:billing_address2}
{field:billing_address3}
{field:billing_country}
{field:billing_postcode}
```

etc...

Are you using these fields in your checkout?

Also, double-check that you have entered in all your Paypal Express Checkout details correctly in the Payment Gateway part of Store:

> PayPal Express Checkout requires an API Username, Password, and
>   Signature. These are different from your PayPal account details. You
>   can obtain your API details by logging in to your PayPal account, and
>   clicking Profile > My Selling Tools > API Access > Request/View API
>   Credentials > Request API Signature.

Does this all check out?

Comment: The fields seem correct, and Store collects those details correctly in the order pages.

I'm using test API settings so the method you get those is different from what is above, but they are correct.

I looked at some the showcase sites on the Store homepage and found one that uses Paypal which has the same issue: http://sanshee.com/
You enter billing info in the Store checkout and then when you pay by guest you have to enter all the info again.

Comment: I've not used Paypal Express with Store myself but that does sound like it could be a minor problem with the Paypal Express gateway as I can't imagine even Paypal would make it *that* hard for the user. I'm sure Adrian or Justin can come along soon to confirm soon.